# Failed to fetch data from api - unable to connect to server -('Access-Control-Allow-Origin)error

Tags: reactjs, nodemailer, connection-refused

I'm trying to submit form and receive the data on mail but it's not workig. it's showing..  http://localhost:4000/contact net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I tried use various options in cors.here are the server side code and client side code[[server side code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rlt9.png)][[client side code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWVaS.png)]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: "*"
}));
```

and make sure that your server is up and running.